# Pi Zero W and Oled Display via HAT?

Tags: display

Beginning playing with PI, I am looking for a display that I can attached onto my **Pi Zero W**.

Very sorry that I am not very familiar with all the connectors. Could I ask whether is is possible to use the **onboard I/O** (not hdmi) to use this display: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33042797757.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no -- not on the Zero.

Other models of Pi have a DSI/MIPI ribbon connector which that is intended for.  But the Pi Zero only has the CSI (camera) connector.

> possible to use the onboard I/O (not hdmi)

The only connector on the Pi Zero with the potential for video is the HDMI jack.  The USB is 2.0, which no one makes screens for as far as I am aware (just VGA and HDMI adapters, which I would be wary of on the Pi).